# How do I set Simulink coder compiler version to one that supports C++11?

Tags: c++, matlab, c++11, simulink

I've got code I'm trying to incorporate into Simulink and its embedded coder.  The code uses C++11 extensions.  Running `mex -setup c++` gives this output:

```
$ mex -setup c++
MEX configured to use 'Xcode Clang++' for C++ language compilation.
```

When I build I get a series of C++11 warnings (`-Wc++11-extensions`), so it would appear that the compiler that Simulink is using is not the default one, which is this:

```
$ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

I don't get an option to select which compiler is used by Simulink and embedded coder, how can I do this please?

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: r2015. @Daniel, I'm using Xcode 6, which appears to be supported according to the link you provide. Perhaps I need to add a -std=c++11 flag to the Simulink toolchain?

Comment: Deleted my comment, miss-interpreted the output.