# How to customise Matlab Simulink toolchain default values?

Tags: matlab, simulink, matlab-compiler

This relates to this question here - [How do I set Simulink coder compiler version to one that supports C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35852882/how-do-i-set-simulink-coder-compiler-version-to-one-that-supports-c11?noredirect=1#comment59373457_35852882)

My understanding of the Matlab Simulink coder process is that a registered toolchain is used to create a makefile and the makefile is then used to build the code that is generated by the coder.

I think the default toolchain within Simulink is not setting the `-std=c++11` flag within the CXXFLAGS in the makefile.  However, when I edit the makefile and then press the generate code button, the makefile is overwritten.  I think I need to edit the toolchain defaults, so that this flag is set.

The Simulink documentation [Create and Edit Toolchain Definition File](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/create-toolchain-definition-file.html)  shows how to create a toolchain from scratch.  There seems to be now information on how to edit an existing installed toolchain.  Can anyone please advise on how I can edit an existing toolchain's default values?

Comment: Can you set "Build configuration" under "code generation" in config parameters to Specify and change compiler options? This will be only for a single model though.

Comment: Yes, thanks very much, that works. However, if you change the selected toolchain in the drop down menu (by accident, as I did), then the changes you make are overwritten.  This has fixed my problem in the short-term, as ideally it would be nice to be able to change the configuration permanently.